# Probably easy question: How to make the Text font in the subscript?

Tags: graphics, text, scripting, fonts, subscript

In the specific Graphic setting, precisely

[image]

(somehow \ ( and \ ) are not shown properly below in Stackexchange window)

> Graphics[Text[Style["\ !\ (1234_L\ )",LineSpacing->{0,12}],{0,3}]]

I am trying to make this looks like $$1234_{\text{L}}$$ with the L as the text font and the 1234 are in the math font. But it apppears as $$1234_{L}$$ with the $L$ as the math font. This outputs

[image]

Ironically, if I use

[image]

> Graphics[Text[Style["\ !\ (1234_Line\ )",LineSpacing->{0,12}],{0,3}]]

it appears as $1234_{\text{Line}}.$ This outputs the desired textfont:

[image]

**Question**: How to get the text font: $1234_{\text{L}}$ in this specific Graphic setting?

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue with your code but the single character seems to be getting italicized as a variable under traditional formatting. In the use of `Subscript(1234,"L")` it will not get italicized because you are telling Mathematica that it is a string. But if you use `Subscript[1234,L]` then the L is italicized.

Comment: thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4):

Usually `FormatType` should be sufficient and you can uncomment the line to note the difference. I have used `Subscript` for finer control over the font.

```
Graphics[{
  Style[Text[Subscript["1234", "L"], {2, 5}],
    Red, 20, FontFamily -> "Times"]},
 Frame -> True,
 (*FormatType\[Rule]StandardForm,*)
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {4, 6}}]
```

[image]